# If I have a thread instance with variable name myThread, how can I find out if it is in the state RUNNABLE?

Tags: java

I looked at this api but didn't find the information I was looking for:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#RUNNABLE

Answer (score 1):

Well if you've already got a thread reference, you can just use [`Thread.getState()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState%28%29):

```
Thread.State state = myThread.getState();
if (state == Thread.State.RUNNABLE) {
    ...
}
```

However, be warned that due to the nature of threads, the state can easily change between the call to `getState()` and your use of the result. It's rarely a good idea to use `getState()` other than for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: +1 for warning - that's good point `state can easily change between the call to getState()`

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
if (myThread.getState() == Thread.State.RUNNABLE)
```

(See [the Javadoc for `Thread.getState()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState%28%29).)